# Validation for Radio Buttons using Knockout

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm facing problem with validation for radio buttons using knockout.

Here is fiddle showing my problem - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/83zLA/).

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked:agree" name="agree" />agree
    <br />
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked:agree" name="agree" />disagree
    <br />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:vehicle" value="bike" />bike
    <br />
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked:vehicle" value="car" />car
    <br />

agree: ko.observable().extend({
    required: true
}),
vehicle: ko.observable().extend({
    required: true
}),
save: function () {
    if (this.isValid()) {
        alert('success');
    }
    else {
        this.errors.showAllMessages();
        alert('error');
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems working. Whats the problem you are facing ?

Comment: it does not showing error messages for radio buttons..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a value on your radio:

```
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked:agree" name="agree" value="1" />agree
<input type="radio" data-bind="checked:agree" name="agree" value="2" />disagree
```

As for the messages, you need to use the `validationMessage` binding when your observable is not bound using the `value` binding (here you use the `checked` binding):

```
<span data-bind="validationMessage: agree"></span>
```

**Edit:**

If you need to force the user to check the box, you will need to create your own rule:

```
ko.validation.rules['trueOnly'] = {
                                     validator: function(val) {
                                                                 return val;
                                     },
                                     message: "This checkbox is required"
                                     }
ko.validation.registerExtenders();
```

Then extend like this:

```
vehicle: ko.observable().extend({
             trueOnly: true
         }),
```

Check it out [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/86Qhh/2/)

### Update after comment:

To check whether at least one is true, you need several changes:

1. Create two different observables, one per checkbox
2. Create a different rule, to validate if at least one has been checked

Validation rule might look like this:

```
ko.validation.rules['oneOrMoreChecked'] = {
    validator: function (val, params) {
            return val || params.otherVal();
        },
        message: "This checkbox is required"
    }
```

And validation declaration:

```
vm().vehicle.extend({
    oneOrMoreChecked: {
        otherVal: vm().vehicle2
    }
});
```

**Update [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/86Qhh/3/)**

Comment: Can you please suggest me what would be the better solution for check box..?

Comment: What do you expect the user to enter? You can't ask the user to always check the box, what's the point? Don't you need a radio instead?

Comment: Thanks for your help...Apart from that i want to know how we are doing validation for check box...

Comment: A checkbox gives a true/false value. Why do you want to add a validation to that? If the user lets it blank, you will get an error, and if the user checks it, the validation will pass. So basically the user should always check the box. Is this what you want?

Comment: Ok, I updated before your comment... I'll update again!